# Build UITableView with preset final row that gets pushed as other rows load asynchronously

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to replicate iOS wifi network view where "Other" row in the list of available wifi networks is showed right away as the only row. As wifi networks get discovered by the device new rows asynchronously are inserted for each network above the "Other" row.

I can create two different row identifiers for the UITableView but how do I load them on different threads and keep "Other" row always at the bottom of the list?

Comment: Just use multiple sections.  But to be clear, you can't update the table view asynchronously.  Code that updates your data source can happen asynchronously, but you'll have to do any UI code on the main thread.

Comment: You can simply return `count+1` in `numberOfRowsInSection` and then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` handle the last row correctly (ie if row == count). As you retrieve the other rows, put the new data into your tableview array and dispatch a row insert in the main thread. You need to make sure only one thread updates the array at a time as array updates aren't thread safe